# ETS (error, trend, seasonal) formulation

Tags: forecasting

Does someone know if there is (clever) way to formulate mathematically all the following models below:

[image]

In a unique (system) of equations?

Comment: [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) would be a much better fit for this question. Consider moving it there.

Comment: Is there a buton to do that or do i have to rewrite the question there?

Comment: I think you need to do it manually.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Cross Validated where it has already been posted.